# python regex sub replace the whole string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I want to replace string that start with `abc` with `replacement`:

```
import re

s = 'abcdefg'

re.sub(r'^abc', 'replacement', s)
replacementdefg
```

What should I do to only return `replacement` instead of `replacementdefg`?

Comment: You can append `.*` to the pattern.

Comment: Why `RegEx`. Why not `startswith()`? Or is your sample not representative?

Comment: Is `startswith()` preferable? If yes, why?

Comment: Well, it's a build-in function and won't need importing. I'm not into technicalities, but I guess it's prefered.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the explanation. In this case I'm using `pandas.Series.str.replace()` so there will be no additional importing needed. But good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the rest of the string with a `.*`

```
import re

s = 'abcdefg'

s = re.sub(r'^abc.*', 'replacement', s)
print(s)
```

output:

```
replacement
```